# Accessing a shared library function through PLT

Tags: shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

There is something I can't understand about accessing a shared library function from user code.

I can't figure why PLT is necessary in that case. My own code is not shared so it can be changed, so why don't we see in what address the function of the shared library was loaded and change the code to access it directly instead of going through PLT each time.

Is it because I can't know that address until my own code is loaded to the memory?

What exactly is the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My own code is not shared so it can be changed,

Your own code is not shared *only* if you run a single copy of your program on the system. If you run more than one copy, then your code *is* shared between processes, and writing to it would prevent such sharing.

Note: this is for *independent* invocations of your executable. Sharing is still possible even for modified code if the multiple processes have parent/child relationship.

There is an additional consideration for `x86_64` ELF systems: in default memory model (`-mcmodel=medium`) there is simply not enough space in e.g. `CALL` instruction to call an arbitrary address: you can only call to addresses +/-2GiB away from current instruction. Since the target of the call may be (often is) further away, you'll need to through PLT entry anyway.

Finally, calling through PLT allows for lazy symbol resolution, which defers runtime cost to the time when a function is called, and is *only* done for function which *are* called. Relocating the code directly would make your code behave as if `LD_BIND_NOW=1` was in effect, making your binary slower to start (sometimes *significantly* slower).